# Aumentar limite de envio de arquivo pelo App.Config C#?

Tags: c#, app.config

Estou com um problema, utilizamos um sistema de envio de arquivos que foi feito em WebApplication e vamos implementá-lo também em uma dll.
No WebApplication é possível configurar no **Web.config** o tamanho máximo do arquivo a ser enviado, utilizando as tags **maxRequestLength (IIS <= 6)** ou **maxAllowedContentLength (IIS >=7)**.
Porém essas mesmas tags não funcionam no **app.Config** da dll e por isso gera o erro abaixo:

> `System.Net.WebException: Falha na solicitação com status HTTP 404: Not Found.
>   em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>   em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)...`

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso configurar o tamanho máximo do arquivo pelo `app.Config`?

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser configurada no web.config da aplicação que vai utilizar esta DLL.

Acredito que você não conseguirá configurar os parâmetros de aplicação maxRequestLength, maxAllowedContentLength através da DLL, pois estes parâmetros são globais.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, tente realizar a configuração das duas variáveis no mesmo arquivo:

Adicionando a variável "maxRequestLenght":

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 </system.web>
```

Adicionando a variável "maxAllowedContentLength":

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000" />
        </requestFiltering> 
 </security>
```

verifique se você esta autorizando o acesso do método que você está acessando:

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
 </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```